# Mask of Madness - How does the Bonus damage recieved work?

Tags: dota-2

I ask about this ability: http://wiki.teamliquid.net/dota2/Mask_of_Madness
Unfortunately the wiki has not alot of information about the extra damage recieved:
"Bonus Damage taken: 30%"

How does this Bonus Damage work?

1. With other sources of bonus damage?

   - Additive,
   - Multiplicative?
2. Which attacks will get you extra damage?

   - Physical attacks,
   - Spells,
   - Reflect,
   - Poison damage*?
3. What kind of extra damage will it be?

   - The same kind as the attack?
   - Physical,
   - Magical,
   - "Pure Damage"*?
4. Can I reduce the extra damage?

   - Armor,
   - Magic Resist,
   - Magic Immunity
   - "Evasion"*?

Stars-Explanation:

- Poison damage: Damage Over Time
- "Pure Damge": Damage that ignores Resistances such as armor or magic resist
- "Evasion": There is on the one hand Evasion vs Physical damage against hits, and on the other hand there is atleast one Passive that I know of that has a chance to evades Spells

Answer (score 2):

The Mask of Madness active applies a debuff which is called [**damage amplification**](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Damage_amplification). When under this status you will recieve 30% more damage from all sources except [**HP removal**](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Damage_types#HP_Removal). The damage type (for the Mask of Madness) is the same as the attack itself, thus the damage can be reduced by armor/magic resistance. The damage however can not be evaded as the damage are added to the source when it hits. You can however evade (with [**normal evasion**](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Evasion)) the attack itself : in that case you won't undergo any bonus damage (since you don't get hit). If you are Void you even have 25% chance of [**backtracking**](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Backtrack#Backtrack) magical damage. Magic amplification stack with other source of magic amplification multiplicatively.